# Looking for a step through an example of a factor analysis on dichotomous data (binary variables) using R

Tags: r, factor-analysis, psychometrics, binary-data

I have some dichotomous data, only binary variables, and my boss asked me to perform a factor analysis using the tetrachoric correlations matrix. I’ve previously been able to teach myself how to run different analyses based on the examples here and at the [UCLA’s stat site](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/) and other sites like it, but I can’t seem to find a step through an example of a factor analysis on dichotomous data (binary variables) using R.

I did see [chl's response](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11372/recommended-procedure-for-factor-analysis-on-dichotomous-data-with-r/11642#11642) to a somewhat simular question and I also saw [ttnphns' answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16331/how-to-perform-principal-components-analysis-on-binary-yes-no-data-using-spss/16335#16335), but I am looking for something even more *spelled out*, a step through an example I can work with.

Does anyone here know of such a *step through an example* of a factor analysis on binary variables using R?

#### Update 2012-07-11 22:03:35Z

I should also add that I am working with an established instrument, that have three dimension, to which we have added some additional questions and we now hope to find four distinct dimension.
Furthermore, our sample size is only $n=153$, and we currently have $19$ items. I compared our sample size and our number of items to a number of psychology articles and we are definitely in the lower end, but we wanted to try it anyway.
Though, this is not important for the *step through example* I am looking for and caracal’s [example below](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31948/looking-for-a-step-through-an-example-of-a-factor-analysis-on-dichotomous-data/32136#32136) looks really amazing. I will work my way thru it using my data first thing in the morning.

Comment: As FA might not necessarily be the best choice, depending on the question you are interested in, could you say more on the context of your study?

Comment: @chl, thank you for responding to my question, we are investigating the underlying factor _structure_ of some questions regarding PTSD. We are interested in 1) identifying some _domains_ (clusters) and 2) investigate how much the different questions _load_ on each _domain_.

Comment: Just to be sure, (a) what is your sample size, (b) is this an existing (already validated) instrument or a self-made questionnaire?

Comment: @chl, I really appreciate your questions. (a) Our sample size is $n=153$, and we currently have 19 items. I compared our sample size and our number of items to what I could find in Journal of Traumatic Stress and we are definitely in the lower end, but we wanted to try it anyway. (b) We are using an existing instrument, but with some self-made questions added as we believe _they are missing_.

Comment: Ok, thanks for this. That should be easy to set up a working example with illustration in R.

Comment: @chl, I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Would you set up such an example or do you know of a site or a book that have such an example I can look at or do you mean it should be easy for me to set up an example?  For the record, [this is the kind of ensamples]( http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/dae/) I’m looking for. I in particular like the [Robust Regression exsample](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/R/dae/rreg.htm). Thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4088/discussion-between-chl-and-eric-fail)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I take it the focus of the question is less on the theoretical side, and more on the practical side, i.e., how to implement a factor analysis of dichotomous data in R.

First, let's simulate 200 observations from 6 variables, coming from 2 orthogonal factors. I'll take a couple of intermediate steps and start with multivariate normal continuous data that I later dichotomize. That way, we can compare Pearson correlations with polychoric correlations, and compare factor loadings from continuous data with that from dichotomous data and the true loadings.

```
set.seed(1.234)
N <- 200                             # number of observations
P <- 6                               # number of variables
Q <- 2                               # number of factors

# true P x Q loading matrix -> variable-factor correlations
Lambda <- matrix(c(0.7,-0.4, 0.8,0, -0.2,0.9, -0.3,0.4, 0.3,0.7, -0.8,0.1),
                 nrow=P, ncol=Q, byrow=TRUE)
```

Now simulate the actual data from the model $x = \Lambda f + e$, with $x$ being the observed variable values of a person, $\Lambda$ the true loadings matrix, $f$ the latent factor score, and $e$ iid, mean 0, normal errors.

```
library(mvtnorm)                      # for rmvnorm()
FF  <- rmvnorm(N, mean=c(5, 15), sigma=diag(Q))    # factor scores (uncorrelated factors)
E   <- rmvnorm(N, rep(0, P), diag(P)) # matrix with iid, mean 0, normal errors
X   <- FF %*% t(Lambda) + E           # matrix with variable values
Xdf <- data.frame(X)                  # data also as a data frame
```

Do the factor analysis for the continuous data. The estimated loadings are similar to the true ones when ignoring the irrelevant sign.

```
> library(psych) # for fa(), fa.poly(), factor.plot(), fa.diagram(), fa.parallel.poly, vss()
> fa(X, nfactors=2, rotate="varimax")$loadings     # factor analysis continuous data
Loadings:
     MR2    MR1   
[1,] -0.602 -0.125
[2,] -0.450  0.102
[3,]  0.341  0.386
[4,]  0.443  0.251
[5,] -0.156  0.985
[6,]  0.590
```

Now let's dichotomize the data. We'll keep the data in two formats: as a data frame with ordered factors, and as a numeric matrix. `hetcor()` from package `polycor` gives us the polychoric correlation matrix we'll later use for the FA.

```
# dichotomize variables into a list of ordered factors
Xdi    <- lapply(Xdf, function(x) cut(x, breaks=c(-Inf, median(x), Inf), ordered=TRUE))
Xdidf  <- do.call("data.frame", Xdi) # combine list into a data frame
XdiNum <- data.matrix(Xdidf)         # dichotomized data as a numeric matrix

library(polycor)                     # for hetcor()
pc <- hetcor(Xdidf, ML=TRUE)         # polychoric corr matrix -> component correlations
```

Now use the polychoric correlation matrix to do a regular FA. Note that the estimated loadings are fairly similar to the ones from the continuous data.

```
> faPC <- fa(r=pc$correlations, nfactors=2, n.obs=N, rotate="varimax")
> faPC$loadings
Loadings:
   MR2    MR1   
X1 -0.706 -0.150
X2 -0.278  0.167
X3  0.482  0.182
X4  0.598  0.226
X5  0.143  0.987
X6  0.571
```

You can skip the step of calculating the polychoric correlation matrix yourself, and directly use `fa.poly()` from package `psych`, which does the same thing in the end. This function accepts the raw dichotomous data as a numeric matrix.

```
faPCdirect <- fa.poly(XdiNum, nfactors=2, rotate="varimax")    # polychoric FA
faPCdirect$fa$loadings        # loadings are the same as above ...
```

EDIT: For factor scores, look at package `ltm` which has a `factor.scores()` function specifically for polytomous outcome data. An example is provided on [this page](http://eur.academia.edu/DimitrisRizopoulos/Teaching) -> "Factor Scores - Ability Estimates".

You can visualize the loadings from the factor analysis using `factor.plot()` and `fa.diagram()`, both from package `psych`. For some reason, `factor.plot()` accepts only the `$fa` component of the result from `fa.poly()`, not the full object.

```
factor.plot(faPCdirect$fa, cut=0.5)
fa.diagram(faPCdirect)
```

[image: output from factor.plot() and fa.diagram()]

Parallel analysis and a "very simple structure" analysis provide help in selecting the number of factors. Again, package `psych` has the required functions. `vss()` takes the polychoric correlation matrix as an argument.

```
fa.parallel.poly(XdiNum)      # parallel analysis for dichotomous data
vss(pc$correlations, n.obs=N, rotate="varimax")   # very simple structure
```

Parallel analysis for polychoric FA is also provided by the package `random.polychor.pa`.

```
library(random.polychor.pa)    # for random.polychor.pa()
random.polychor.pa(data.matrix=XdiNum, nrep=5, q.eigen=0.99)
```

[image: output from fa.parallel.poly() and random.polychor.pa()]

Note that the functions `fa()` and `fa.poly()` provide many many more options to set up the FA. In addition, I edited out some of the output which gives goodness of fit tests etc. The documentation for these functions (and package `psych` in general) is excellent. This example here is just intended to get you started.

Comment: [Your _step through example_](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31948/looking-for-a-step-through-an-example-of-a-factor-analysis-on-dichotomous-data/32136#32136) looks great. I will work my way thru it using my data in the morning and get back to you. Thank you for taking the time to write this. If you happen to have some theoretical references I would also be interested in them. [Chl](http://stats.stackexchange.com/users/930/chl) recommended [Revelle's textbook for psychometrics in R](http://personality-project.org/r/book/) and I am definitely going to take a look at that. Thanks

Comment: @caracal: does `psych` allow somehow to estimate _factor scores_ when poly/tetra-choric correlations are used in place of usual Pearson r?

Comment: @ttnphns Try `factor.scores(x=XdiNum, f=faPCdirect$fa, method="Bartlett")` with the above example. Also from package `psych`.

Comment: Sorry, @caracal, I'm not R user. That's _why_ I'm asking it. Since you've used not original Pearson r but tetrachoric r you've lost straightforward linear-algebraic link between original binary data and the loading matrix. I imagine that in this case some special algo would be used (e.g. based on EM approach) in place of classic regression/Bartlett one. So does `psych` give its due to the fact that we were dealing with tetrachoric r, not usual r, when it computes factor scores, or doesn't?

Comment: @caracal: again, thanks you for your great answer. I get everything working, but I get a warning that in `cor.smooth(mat)` the `Matrix was not positive definite, smoothing was done`. I imagine this have to do with my many items and few observations? Do you happen to know if there is some way to try to resolve this or investigate this issue further? Thanks

Comment: @EricFail As polychoric correlation matrices are estimated by going through the pairwise correlations, a non positive definite end matrix indeed becomes more common as the number of variables increases, and the number of observations is fixed (see this [MPlus discussion](http://www.statmodel.com/discussion/messages/8/2243.html?1303851375)). Functions like `nearcor()` from `sfsmisc` or `cor.smooth()` from `psych` are used for this case.

Comment: @ttnphns Sorry, I misunderstood your question. Good question! I originally assumed that something like MPlus technical appendix 11 was implemented, but looking at the code for `psych`'s `factor.scores()`, this is not the case. Instead, scores are calculated just like in the continuous case. However, the `factor.scores()` function in package `ltm` seems to implement the correct procedures, see this [example](http://eur.academia.edu/DimitrisRizopoulos/Teaching) -> "Factor Scores - Ability Estimates" and the help page.