# Muthén's robust weighted least squares factoring method for binary items...in R?

Tags: r, factor-analysis, mplus

I am working on an exploratory factor analysis of dichotomous items.  I've found [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31948/looking-for-a-step-through-an-example-of-a-factor-analysis-on-dichotomous-data) extremely helpful. However, Mplus seems to be a standard that journals in my field are expecting, and I would love to replicate Mplus results in R.

I've gotten my results to come very close to Mplus, using the fa function on a polychoric correlation matrix (created with the hetcor function) and the geominQ rotation.  It seems that the major difference between the fa function and Mplus is that the latter uses a robust weighted least squares factoring method (WLSMV - a diagonal weight matrix), whereas the former uses a regular weighted least squares (WLS) factoring method.

Has anyone managed to use R to replicate Mplus factor analysis for binary items? Has anyone figured out how to implement WLSMV in R?

Thanks!

Comment: aside...Mplus can also generate bootstrap standard errors - advised to try and account for the extra variability in polychorics - see ch12 of mplus examples on how to implement.

Answer (score 9):

What you want is in the `lavaan` package, the function is named `sem`. Try writing an argument `estimator = "WLSMV"`. For more information read [this](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lavaan/lavaan.pdf).

Comment: i dont think there is an example of efa in lavaan package but look at efa in a cfa framework example at http://www.amarkos.gr/research/lavaan/ for how to implement. Wish i had noticed this before.

Comment: Thanks AAA and user20650, this is looking promising -- I'm still messing around with the options for the sem function and will update here once I figure it out.